# Why might someone mount the rear wheels at an angle?

Tags: wheels

I observed a very strange car a few days ago when driving:

The rear wheels are mounted at an angle. Meaning, the plane of rotation is not vertical; rather, the distance between the wheels is wider at the bottom and narrower at the top. Here is an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

I was worried that the wheels might come off, but they did not. I also observed that the tire seems to be wider and larger in diameter than the standard tire. There is a chance that the larger wheel will not fit in the original space of the chassis but I am not sure.

The vehicle was a Lexus if that information is relevant. I was not able to drive close enough to note the model, but it appears otherwise to be an ordinary saloon.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is "negative camber" and there are a few things that could be going on.  First, if the wheels were at an *extreme* angle, then there is a style called "stanced".  It serves no purpose other than aesthetic.  It quickly ruins tires and destroys the handling of the car and is really only for looks and normally includes the car being so low that it barely clears the ground.

[image: Stanced car]

If it was only a slight angle, and the car was lowered, certain DIY suspension modifications can lower the car and also result in the wheels being off camber.  Of course, some suspension parts could just be worn or broken which can have the same result without necessarily lowering the car.

[image: Bad rear tire camber from broken suspension]

Comment: I noted that the arrangement was symmetrical and the tires was definitely after-market made; the angle also appeared similar to the first picture. So I believe it is the first case. I did not recall an unusual low ground clearance, probably due to the roads of the city I am in I guess.

Comment: Some people are purist and will drop the car until it scrapes.  Some are a little more "practical" and stance the wheels without dropping the car all the way so they can still actually get in and out of driveways, etc.